# Apply CSS without class and id on sibling element

Tags: html, css

I need to apply different background-color on the following divs from CSS files without using classes or ids

```
<div>This is Blue</div>
<div>This is Yello</div>
<div>This is Red</div>
```

Is there any way to do that without using JavaScript or jQuery

Comment: I had already used nth-child property there is some problem if I have children divs. i am looking for some sibling css property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A odd way to go about it is with nth-of-type, it works but could get oddly complicated if used with lots of other divs on the page.

I added some extra divs just to demo that this method can be selective enough.

```css
.thisone div:nth-of-type(1n) {
  background: rgb(100, 100, 100);
}

.thisone div:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background: rgb(80, 80, 80);
}

.thisone div:nth-of-type(3n) {
  background: rgb(60, 60, 60);
}

.thisone div:nth-of-type(4n) {
  background: rgb(40, 40, 40);
}

.thisone div:nth-of-type(5n) {
  background: rgb(20, 20, 20);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>First</div>
  <div>Second</div>
  <div>Third</div>
  <div>Fourth</div>
  <div>Fifth</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="thisone">
  <div>First</div>
  <div>Second</div>
  <div>Third</div>
  <div>Fourth</div>
  <div>Fifth</div>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <div>First</div>
  <div>Second</div>
  <div>Third</div>
  <div>Fourth</div>
  <div>Fifth</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is helpful for me thanks, but I change the formula  using plus sign.   Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can use CSS `:nth-child()` selector like this:

```
div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: blue;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: It will append to all children tag its a kind of siblling .If I have any child divs it  will apply too also.

Comment: You mean you want to target the first level? Like not the children elements? Can you post all of your code?

Comment: Yes I want to target  all the first level element not the children

Answer (score 1):

```css
div:nth-child(1){
background:blue;
}
div:nth-child(2){
background:yellow;
}
div:nth-child(3){
background:red;
}
```

```html
<div>This is Blue</div>
<div>This is Yello</div>
<div>This is Red</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the current structure of the div is *Not Nested*, so using the **`CSS :nth-child()`** is not appropriate.
For this case we can use `Sibling Selector` present in CSS:

1. **adjacent sibling selector (+)**

   The adjacent sibling selector selects all elements that are the adjacent siblings of a specified element.

   The following example selects all `<p>` elements that are placed immediately after `<div>` elements:

   > div + p {
   >       background-color: yellow; 
   >   }
2. **general sibling selector (~)**

   The general sibling selector selects all elements that are siblings of a specified element.
   The following example selects all `<p>` elements that are siblings of `<div>` elements:

   > div ~ p {
   >       background-color: yellow; 
   >   }

Hope it helps.